# Dart - Future inside Future not functioning properly

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, dart

so I have this code:

```
getAllDiscussionsFromDb() async {

  List<Discussion> discussionsToReturn = [];

  List<Discussion> returnDiscussions(var args){
    return discussionsToReturn;
  }

  var discussionsFromDb = await database.query("select * from discussions");
  // We have to instantiate actual discussion objects from the database columns
  return discussionsFromDb.forEach((discussion) async {
    int discussionId = discussion[4];
    var comments;
    comments = await getCommentsOfDiscussion(discussionId);
    discussionsToReturn.add(new Discussion(discussion[0], discussion[1], discussion[2], discussion[3], comments));
  }).then(returnDiscussions);
}
```

The only problem with it is the comments = ... line.

this is the getCommentsOfDiscussion function:

```
getCommentsOfDiscussion(id) async {

  List<SingleComment> allComments = [];

  List<SingleComment> returnComments(var args) {
    return allComments;
  }

  var commentsFromDb = await database.query("select * from comments where discussionId = $id");
  // We have to instantiate actual SingleComment objects from the database columns
  return commentsFromDb.forEach((comment) async {
    allComments.add(new SingleComment(comment[0], comment[1], comment[2], comment[3]));
  }).then(returnComments);
}
```

If I replace the comments = await ... with comments = [], my code works perfectly fine. There must be some sort of error with the await. I tried using .then instead of await, but then I get an error that I can't use call on null.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line `return discussionsFromDb.forEach((discussion) async {` looks weird. `forEach` doesn't return a `Future`, it returns `void`.

Therefore `).then(returnDiscussions);` is invalid.

Perhaps

```
  await for(var discussion in discussionsFromDb) {
    int discussionId = discussion[4];
    var comments;
    comments = await getCommentsOfDiscussion(discussionId);
    discussionsToReturn.add(new Discussion(discussion[0], discussion[1], discussion[2], discussion[3], comments));
  }
  return discussionsToReturn;
```

is what you want